# Keep unformated values while opening an Excel-file with Python

Tags: python, pandas, excel, csv, openpyxl

**Background:**

We provide our suppliers an excel-file, that they have to fill out. They have to fill out the cells in column I, starting at row 11 (See Picture: Head of the excel-file). In these cells they have to input values for exapmple like this: 8,76545 or 0,98565. (The decimal seperator is a comma: ,). The supplier decides, in which cells they add a value in column I. So some cells can be empty. The rows 1 to 9 in the excel-file can be ignored for this problem. Unfortunately the cells in column I are formated as percentage.

Head of the excel-file: [Head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoLf6.png)

Example with filled values: [Filled Cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ulrq.png)

We get the filled file back as excel-file or csv-file.

We remove the rows 1 to 9 aswell as all rows, that have no value in column I (starting at row 11), we convert the excel file into csv and upload them into our ERP-System. This is done manually.

The goal is to automate this steps/process with Python:

- Ignore rows 1 to 9
- remove all rows with empty cells in column I (starting at row 11)
- remove the percentage format
- save the result as csv

The result should look like this: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BO3gK.png)

**Problem:**

We are getting the filled file back as excel- or csv-file, with or without the percentage format. The excel-file with the percentage format is problematic.

If I open the excel-file, with the percentage format with pandas, pandas ist converting the values like this:.

- Original value in the excel file: 8,61565740319208%
- Converted value by pandas: 0.0861565740319208

The value should be 8,61565740319208% befor I remove the percentage sign with Python. (The dot-decimal seperator is not a problem)

Since the suppliers delivers the excel-files with or withou the percentage format, I just cant multiply the values in pandas by 100. Pandas is converting the values automatically, so I have no chance to check, if there is a % or not in the cell. I am using openpyxl as engine.

While my code is multiplying the values with 100, this is wrong.

**Code:**

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

def clear_date(date: str) -> str:
    if len(date.strip()) == 10 and "." in date: #10.02.2023
        return date
    elif len(date.strip()) > 10 and "-" in date:
        return datetime.fromisoformat(date).strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
    

def clear_faktor(faktor: str) -> str:
    try:
        faktor = faktor.replace("%","")

        if "," in faktor:
            return f"{faktor:0<8}"[:8]
        elif float(faktor) < 0.1:
            return f"{str(float(faktor[:10])*100).replace(".", ","):0<8}"[:8]
        else:
            return f"{faktor:0<8}"[:8]
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
    

def clear_LF(lf: str) -> str:
    if lf == "LF10":
        return "LFA"
    else:
        return lf


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Set Path
    path_main = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    path_offer = os.path.join(path_main, "Offer")
    path_cleared = os.path.join(path_main, "Cleared")

    #create necessary folders"
    if not os.path.exists(path_offer):
        os.makedirs(path_offer)
    if not os.path.exists(path_cleared):
        os.makedirs(path_cleared)

    original_files = iter(os.listdir(path_offer))


    #Clear files
    for file in original_files:
        o_file = pd.DataFrame()
        
        if os.path.splitext(file)[1].upper() == ".XLSX":
            try:
                o_file = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(path_offer, file), dtype="str")
            except PermissionError:
                continue

        elif os.path.splitext(file)[1].upper() == ".CSV":
            try:
                o_file = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path_offer, file), dtype="str", sep=";", encoding_errors="ignore")
            except PermissionError:
                continue
        else:
            continue

        index_header = o_file[o_file.isin(["Typ", "MODEL_GUID", "VALID_FROM", "VALID_TO", "LAUFZEIT", "FAKTOR"]).any(axis=1)].index.values
        
        if index_header and index_header.size == 1:
            header = o_file.loc[index_header[0]].values
            o_file = o_file.loc[index_header[0]+1:, :]
            o_file.columns = header
            o_file.dropna(subset=["FAKTOR"], inplace=True)
            o_file["Typ"] = "LF"
            o_file["LF"] = o_file["LF"].apply(clear_LF)
            o_file["VALID_FROM"] = o_file["VALID_FROM"].apply(clear_date)
            o_file["VALID_TO"] = o_file["VALID_TO"].apply(clear_date)
            o_file["FAKTOR"] = o_file["FAKTOR"].apply(clear_faktor)
            o_file = o_file.loc[:, "Typ":"FAKTOR"]

            try:
                o_file.to_csv(os.path.join(path_cleared, f"{os.path.splitext(file)[0]}.csv"), index=False, sep=";", encoding="utf-8")
            except PermissionError:
                continue
        else:
            continue
```

**What I have tried:**

I tried the converters parameter in the read_excel method with this function:

def to_excel(strng):
return str(strng)

The parameter dtype="str" in the read_excel method has also not the effect, I want.

I also tried to open the excel-file with openpyxl, but the result is the same, like opening the file with pandas (pandas is using openpyxl as engine).

Nothing of this is working.

Comment: Excel stores all numeric fields as simple numeric values. The only time they are converted to items such as you refer to is for display. So the values retrieved by Pandas  is correct.